# Uncaught ReferenceError: projection is not defined

Tags: projection

i am trying to load a geojson file to a .html but is giving me the "Uncaught ReferenceError: projection is not defined"

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>  

  </head>
  <body>
    <script>

    var canvas=d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 760)
        .attr("height", 700)    

    d3.json("sweden20.geojson", function(data) {

    var group= canvas.selectAll("g")
            .data(data.features)
            .enter()
            .append("g")

        var pojection = d3.geo.mercator();
        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        var areas= group.append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue");

    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and sweden20.geojson was taken from Sweden in here:http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/

Answer (score 1):

There is a probable typo in this line:

```
var pojection = d3.geo.mercator();
```

Replace `pojection` with `projection` and the reference error should go away.

Comment: btw, any solutions for "Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute " (in the same code)?

Comment: Which line? Your code just gives me a blue rectangle if I run it with `http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/se/se-all.geo.json`.